# A integral involving binomial coefficient

Tags: integration, binomial-coefficients

Is there a function $f(x)$ ($f(x)$ and $n$ are irrelevant) that makes the following relationship true? 
$$\int\limits_{0}^1 x^{n-1}f(x)dx=\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}\quad ?$$
I tried to get the function by using the Merlin transform, but 
I failed.

Comment: This cannot be true, imagine $f(x) = x^{1-n}$, in that case you have

$$
\int_0^1 x^{n-1}f(x) ~{\rm d}x = \int_0^1 x^{n-1}x^{1 - n}~{\rm d}x = \int_0^1 {\rm d}x = 1
$$

independent of $n$

Comment: How about $f(x) = \dbinom{2n}{n}x^{1-n}$? Then you have $$\int_0^1 x^{n-1}f(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\dbinom{2n}{n}x^{1-n}dx = \dbinom{2n}{n}\int_0^1 dx = \dbinom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: If $f(x)$ and $n$ are irrelevant, then $f(x)$ does it exist？

Comment: If such a function exists, it must be oscillating, with an accumulation of zeroes near $x=1$. Because $x^n$ is significantly different from $1$ in a narrow region next to $1$, that goes shrinking. For the result to be a growing function of $n$, there must be a lot of cancellation for the lower $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know the Wallis formula where $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{2n}(x)dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n}(x)dx=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}}{2n\choose n}$$ thus one of the functions can be $f(x)=2^{2n}
\frac{cos^{2n}(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{x^{n-1}}$ there can be many other functions. Look up the Wallis formula for sin and cosine raised to integer powers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want know that if $f(x)$ does not depend on $n$, does it exist？

Comment: I can't think of such a function at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Looking for a $f(x)$ independent from $n$, 
let's put the whole into discrete form, as a Riemann Sum and thus
in matrix form
$$
\eqalign{
  & \int_0^1 {x^{\,n} f(x)\,dx} \quad  \to \quad \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,h - 1} {\left( {{k \over h}} \right)^{\,n} f\left( {{k \over h}} \right){1 \over h}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {h^{\,n + 1} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,h - 1} {k^{\,n} \varphi _h \left( k \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{1 \over {h^{\,n + 1} }} \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  \cdots   \cr 
   0 & 1 & {2^1 } & {3^1 } &  \cdots   \cr 
   0 & 1 & {2^2 } & {3^2 } &  \cdots   \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots   \cr 
   {\left( {h - 1} \right)^0 } & {\left( {h - 1} \right)^1 } & {\left( {h - 1} \right)^2 } & {\left( {h - 1} \right)^3 } &  \cdots   \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {\varphi _h \left( 0 \right)}  \cr 
   {\varphi _h \left( 1 \right)}  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {\varphi _h \left( {h - 1} \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   {\left( \matrix{
  2 \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)}  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {\left( \matrix{
  2h - 2 \cr 
  h - 1 \cr}  \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$
where $\left( {{1 \over {h^{\,n + 1} }} \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)$ is a diagonal matrix with elements  $1/h^{n+1}$

The Vandermonde matrix is invertible, so the system is solvable, leading to a $\varphi _h(k)$.

It remains to see if for $h \to \infty$ $\varphi _h(k/h)$ tends to a definite function.

But applying the formula for the [Vandermonde Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) it is easy to see that the determinant of the two
LHS matrices diminishes rapidly with $h$, so that the determinant of the inverse is rapidly increasing, and so
does the absolute value of $\varphi (k)$, which moreover alternates in sign.
So we can conclude that

> a $f(x)$, independent of $n$, does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a Taylor series: $$f(x) = \sum_{k\ge 0}a_kx^k$$

Then the integral:

$$\int_0^1 x^{n-1}f(x)dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{k\ge 0} a_kx^{k+n-1}dx = \left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \dfrac{a_k}{k+n}\right)$$

Note: This integral is only defined for $n\ge 1$. So, just choose any infinite sum that gives you $\dbinom{2n}{n}$, and you have your answer.